# Connecting to Webservice with httpclient 4.5.2 via squid proxy

Tags: java, authentication, proxy, httpclient, squid

I need to upload files to a Webservice from a Java application. Therefore i use the Apaches HttpClient. Addionally I need to connect through a proxy. In my case this is a squid proxy with Basic Authentication. In the future this could change to other proxies with other authentication types.

This is a snippet of my current code:

```
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

... //fill entity

CredentialsProvider provider = new MyCredentialsProvider();         
HttpRoutePlanner routePlanner = new SystemDefaultRoutePlanner(ProxySelector.getDefault());
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
    .setRoutePlanner(routePlanner)
    .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider)
    .build();

...

HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
post.setHeader("Cookie",cookies); //needed for session
post.setEntity(entity);

...

HttpResponse res = client.execute(post);

...

client.close();
```

MyCredentialsProvider is a selfmade class because HttpClient's SystemDefaultCredentialsProvider seems not to work as expected. It basically uses java.net.Authenticator to request credentials from the user.

With this code everything seems to work fine. I can upload a file without a proxy set in Java Control Panel and with my squid proxy set (no authentication and basic authentication). The problem I have only occures when I upload a file with a slightly bigger size (about 64kb). In this case client.execute(post) runs in a timeout with following exception: [proxy ip]:[proxy port] failed to respond

```
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: [proxy ip]:[proxy port] failed to respond
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:143)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261)
at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:165)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:167)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
...
```

In Wireshark I can see, that HttpClient makes two identical http post requests. One without the http header "Proxy-Authorizatio"n, one with "Proxy-Authorization: Basic ...". The first gets the expected response (407 Proxy Authentication Required). The seconds request gets no response. I can see that both request only contain the first parameter of the multipart entity.

I could reproduce this phenomenon with HttpClient 4.2.1.

Has anyone expierenced this too? I guess this has something to do, that both these requests are made in one http connection. Does anyone knows how to configure either HttpClient or squid proxy to make this work?

Thank you for any help.

**edit:** 
I can increase the maximum file size to about 1mb if I follow the instructions of http://www.nuxeo.com/blog/using-httpclient-properly-avoid-closewait-tcp-connections/. I set a http header before executing the request:

```
post.setHeader("Connection", "close");
```

Files over 1mb give me the following exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.streamWrite(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:126)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.write(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:162)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:115)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:122)
at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.ByteArrayBody.writeTo(ByteArrayBody.java:97)
at org.apache.http.entity.mime.AbstractMultipartForm.doWriteTo(AbstractMultipartForm.java:134)
at org.apache.http.entity.mime.AbstractMultipartForm.writeTo(AbstractMultipartForm.java:157)
at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity.writeTo(MultipartFormEntity.java:113)
at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity.writeTo(MultipartEntity.java:180)
at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:158)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.sendRequestEntity(CPoolProxy.java:162)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:237)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:122)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
```

But this is no solution because i need to upload bigger files (maybe up to 10mb) and multiple files!